# Change RAILS_ENV on shared server without modify passenger configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

How i change the RAILS_ENV to staging without modify the virtual host file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in your .htaccess file, if your host allows it:

```
RailsEnv staging
```

Comment: Thanks. I can overwrite environment.rb ENV['rails_env'] = 'staging'